# Why is there no general form for the harmonic numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

The Harmonic numbers $H_n$ are given by the sum of the reciprocals of the natural numbers up to a given $n$, ie:

$H_1 = 1$

$H_2 = 1 + 1/2 = 3/2$

$H_3 = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 = 11/6$

$H_n$ for noninteger $n$ can be given by the integral definition $$\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx$$

ie: $H_{1/2} = 2-2\ln2$, or $\ln\frac{e^2}{4}$

But as far as I can tell, no general formula (ie: without an integral, a sum, product or a limit as part of the definition) for any $n$ exists. Is there a specific reason why? A proof that one does not exist? Or have we just not found one yet?

Comment: It is hard to imagine something with a nice closed form, that grows like $\log(n)$ but takes only rational values.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://oeis.org/A001008

Comment: For arbitrary $n$, this can be expressed in terms of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function): $H_n=\psi(n+1)+\gamma$

Comment: What constitutes a valid 'general formula' is a very subjective thing.

Comment: There is a satisfactory theory of when an integral $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$, where $f$ is an elementary function, can be expressed in terms of elementary functions. It is natural to ask whether there is a corresponding theory for sums. The problem must have been considered, but I know of no results.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Take a look at A=B: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html.

Comment: Quite a while ago, I read it, with pleasure. A *procedure* is given, that very often works. I do not know of any accompanying "Galois" theory.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I know very little about expressing antiderivatives as elementary functions, but I am interested in your comment, particularly the mention of a Galois theory for such things. Can you suggest a reference?

Comment: Maybe a start would be the Wikipedia article on [Differential Galois Theory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory)

Comment: There *is* a closed form for $H_n$: it's $H_n$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: if you allow the floor function, that becomes easy. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

Since $H_n \sim \log n$, there is no formula for $H_n$ using a rational function of $n$ because $p(x)/q(x) \sim x^k$, for some integer $k$, and $\log x$ is never asymptotic to $x^k$.

Here, $f(x) \sim g(x)$ when $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.

Comment: For the same reason, it isn't possible to express $H_n$ as an algebraic function of $n$.

Comment: @JulianRosen Can you explain in more detail? If $f$ is algebraic why is it necessarily the case that $f(x) \sim x^{\alpha}$?

Comment: An algebraic function $f(x)$ can be expanded as a Puiseux series in $x^{-1}$, i.e. $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_i x^{n_i}$, with $a_i\in\mathbb{C}$, $n_i$ a sequence of rational numbers with bounded denominator heading to $-\infty$. Then $|f(x)|\sim |x|^{\alpha}$ as $x\to\infty$, where $\alpha=\min\{n_i:a_i\neq 0\}\in\mathbb{Q}$. The function $f(x)$ satisfies an identity $\sum_{i=0}^n g_i(x)f(x)^i=0$, with $g_0(x),\ldots,g_n(x)$ rational functions, and the value of $\alpha$ can be computed using the [Newton polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon).

Answer (score 6):

As lhf explained, every rational function grows like some integer power of $x$ as $x\to\infty$. Since $H_n\sim\log n$ as $n\to\infty$, there can be no rational function $f$ with $f(n)=H_n$.

This can be generalized to algebraic functions, which are functions satisfying an equation
$$
\tag{$\star$}
\sum_{i=0}^n a_i(x) f(x)^i =0
$$
for some polynomials $a_0,\ldots,a_n$ not all $0$. If $f$ satisfies $(\star)$, then $|f(x)|\sim C x^\alpha$ as $x\to\infty$ for some constants $C$, $\alpha$, with $\alpha$ a rational number of denominator at most $n$ (the value of $\alpha$ can be computed using Newton polygons). In particular, since there is no $\alpha$ for which $\log(n)\sim C n^\alpha$, there can be no algebraic functions $f$ with $f(n)=H_n$.